# Proving following equation is false

Tags: calculus

Problem:

> If $f(x)$ is continuous and nonnegative on the interval [a, b], then
>   $\int_a^b [f(x)]^{1/3}dx=[\int_a^b f(x)dx]^{1/3}$. Prove that this statement is false.

I dont even know where to start.

Comment: You simply need to find a counter-example. i.e. Think of a specific $f(x)$ and $a,b$ such that this doesn't work.

Comment: Anything would do, really.

Comment: @glowstonetrees Since I am not allowed to use a calculator how would I choose "a" and "b" and the function f?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove false, one only needs a counterexample. Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ over the interval $[-1,1]$. Note that $f(x)$ is continuous and nonnegative on that interval. Then
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt[3]{x^2} dx = \left. \frac{3 \sqrt[3]{x^5}}{5} \right\vert_{x=-1}^1=\frac{6}{5}\neq \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{\left.\frac{x^3}{3}\right\vert_{x=-1}^1} = \sqrt[3]{\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 dx}.$$

Comment: Since I am not allowed to use a calculator how would I choose "a" and "b" and the function f?

Comment: Because the cube root of 2/3 is very hard to find without a calculator

Comment: Just choose an "easy" function over a "simple" domain, as I did here. As @glowstonetrees said, pretty much anything would work.

Comment: Well it's pretty obvious that $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}} \neq \frac{6}{5}$, you don't need to simplify it down. If you do want to prove it, assume they are equal and derive a contradiction. For instance, $$(\frac{2}{3})^{1/3} = \frac{6}{5}$$ $$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{216}{125}$$ $$250 = 648$$ and hence, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks thats smart

Comment: You may also notice that $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}$ is irrational, while $\frac{6}{5}$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^3$

$$\int _0^1 (f(x))^{1/3} = \int _0^1 xdx = 1/2=0.5$$

$$(\int _0^1 f(x)dx )^{1/3} =( \int _0^1 x^3dx)^{1/3} = (1/4)^{1/3} \approx 0.6299$$

We have two different answer so this works as a counter example to the statement.